# Webpack 4 compiler error ERROR in compilation.fileDependencies.push is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I installed a new react project but when compiling the project with webpack 4
it returns the following ERROR in compilation.

> fileDependencies.push is not a function

Thanks in advance

Comment: only that error does not help anything. Please post the whole stack trace.

Comment: Bishoy Bisahi - Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this by installing the latest version of `html-webpack-plugin` as a devDependency.

### Also, try `html-webpack-plugin` instead of <strike>`webpack-html-wplugin`</strike>

Good Luck...

Comment: Omg, for this, I don't know when I would've figured this out. ‍♂️